# What does "barely perceptibly" mean?

Tags: british-english, phrase-meaning

> Barely perceptibly, he starts to cry.

Does *barely perceptibly* mean *losing control*?

Comment: No, it means that his crying is so subdued that it's hard to perceive.

Comment: Look up the two words in a dictionary.

Comment: Signal is just barely above the noise. To determine if it's real, you have to decide how many sigmas you are willing to take for truth: https://www.isixsigma.com/new-to-six-sigma/sigma-level/sigma-performance-levels-one-six-sigma/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the Oxford online dictionary, you will find

> Only just; almost not.

‘she nodded, barely able to speak’
as submodifier ‘a barely perceptible pause’

You might well ask exactly how someone can cry "barely perceptibly" you might well ask.  Strictly it ought to mean that he began to cry, and that what was *barely perceptible* (i.e. almost imperceptible) was his beginning to cry.  In that case, you could imagine the person ending up obviously crying, but very gradually:  almost imperceptible at first and gradually building up into open grief.  The way the passage is phrased suggests this to me. The adverbial phrase "barely perceptibly", placed at the beginning of the sentence and separated by a comma (a move often called 'a *fronted* adverbial) suggests (to me) that it should modify the clause that follows and so the main verb "starts". On the other hand, common sense suggests that what is probably really modified by the adverbial is the verb crying, and that the crying itself was "barely perceptible."